# Why won't nano editor install on my mac?

Tags: linux, permissions, terminal, installation, nano

Ok so I am trying to install nano in terminal on my macbook. I downloaded the file, unzipped it, and located the folder/files in terminal. I ran the ./configure command. Then "make." Both ran fine. On "make install" I keep getting an error about permissions and making a directory. This is what the error is:

```
mkdir: /usr/local: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local: No such file or directory
mkdir: /usr/local/share: No such file or directory
mkdir: /usr/local/share/nano: No such file or directory
make[5]: *** [install-htmlmanDATA] Error 1
make[4]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[3]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: doesn't work. says enter password.. i don't have a password so i hit enter and it says "sorry"

Comment: try configuring it to your home directory. go back to ./configure --prefix=/Users/YOUR_COMP_USERNAME (fill this in with your username), then run make and make install. unfortunately you will need to update your path after that, but it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo make install
```

That should fix it. It is telling you that you (the user) do not have permission to make the given folders, sudo lets you run the program as root who has access to the given directories.

Comment: Should I run sudo ./configure and sudo make?

Comment: Nope, just sudo make install is fine.

Comment: It didn't give an error, but I don't think its installed. Shouldn't nana file.cpp have syntax highlights?

Comment: No, nano does not have syntax highlighting. If it didn't give you a "nano not found" type of error, it has installed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo make install` should do it (as long as you can `sudo`).

Answer (score 0):

To install it like that ( "below" user account ) you should've specified prefix with configure --prefix option ( before compilation, before make command )  To install systemwide use sudo as suggested above. you may also want to use MacPorts.